# How can I properly import a Pipe Module in my Component in Angular 4/Ionic?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive, angular-pipe

So I am getting this error:

```
Template parse errors: The pipe 'orderByDateSubmitted' could not be found.
```

Any my code looks like this:

First, I created a Pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'orderByDateSubmitted'
})

export class OrderByDateSubmittedPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(array: Array<any>, args: string): Array<any> {
    //sort code
  }
}
```

and then I created a Module for this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { OrderByDateSubmittedPipe } from './order-by-date-submitted';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [OrderByDateSubmittedPipe],
  exports: [OrderByDateSubmittedPipe],
})

export class OrderByDateSubmittedPipeModule {}
```

And in my App Module

```
import { OrderByDateSubmittedPipe } from './../pipes/order-by-date-submitted/order-by-date-submitted';
import { OrderByDateSubmittedPipeModule } from './../pipes/order-by-date-submitted/order-by-date-submitted.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [MyApp...],
  imports: [...
    OrderByDateSubmittedPipeModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [...],
  providers: [...]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and I use it in one of my components like this:

```
*ngFor="let r of reports | orderByDateSubmitted: '-date_submitted'"
```

But I'm getting that error. Did I actually do the importing of modules correctly? Or am I missing something? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The component where you use the pipe is part of `AppModule`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes, it is in the imports and entryComponents array

Comment: Components shouldn't be in the `imports` array. It should be in the `declarations` array. `entryComponents` is only required if the component is added dynamically (like `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()`)

Answer (score 1):

ive been stuck on this one for last few hours, couldn't understand why my pipe worked in one project, but when i moved the code to a new project it didnt work.

kept getting error about 'name_of_my_pipe' not being found

I finally realised my app.module.ts was declaring/exporting my 'home-page' twice once as 'MyApp' and the also as 'ListPage'  (i am a complete novice, basically hacking together something from some example code, it looks like when i created the page 'ListPage' using the ionic CLI (which was already the home-page in the app) it auto added the normal page code and references to the app.module.ts)

anyways here is my original app.module.ts

```
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';
import { InfoPage } from '../pages/info/info';
import { MyService } from '../services/rest/service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    ListPage,
    InfoPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    ListPage,
    InfoPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    MyService,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

once i removed the references to ListPage (which remember is already my app home page as declared in app.component.ts

my custom pipe was now recognised

```
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { InfoPage } from '../pages/info/info';
import { MyService } from '../services/rest/service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    InfoPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    InfoPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    MyService,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the `pipe` in your component you have to import the `pipemodule` in to your component level module too. Not only in to `App.module.ts`.

```
|-->App.module.ts (App main component module)
|-->pipes.module.ts (Pipe component module)
|-->Newpage 
      |-->Newpage.module.ts (NewPage component module) <--//Import the pipe module here
```

See [thisAnswer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47577716/5238035) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a module for the pipe. Simply import it in the "Declarations" of your AppModule.

Comment: You need to import the pipe, not the module in your Declarations.

Comment: Yup that's why I did.

Comment: Unexpected pipe 'OrderByDateSubmittedPipe' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ionic 4 and I generated my pipe with ionicCLI command

```
ionic g pipe my-pipe
```

That added imports line of my new pipe in declarations, but not in exports.

That was throwing an error too me.