# Ionic 3: The pipe '' could not be found

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, pipe, ionic3

I can't seem any error regarding this problem. I already import in app.module.ts and put it in 'declaration'.

in app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

//ionic-native
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

//pipe
import { HoursMinutesSecondsPipe } from '../pipes/hours-minutes-
seconds/hours-minutes-seconds';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
MyApp,
HoursMinutesSecondsPipe
],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
  platforms: {
    android: {
      tabsPlacement: 'top'
    }
  }
}),
],
bootstrap: [IonicApp],
entryComponents: [
MyApp,
],
providers: [
StatusBar,
SplashScreen,
{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
NativeStorage,
]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Usage:

```
    <ion-card class="card-container" (click)="onTimer()">
      <img src="assets/imgs/wp1.png"/>
      <div class="card-title">Time Smoke Free</div>
      <div class="card-subtitle">{{ seconds | hoursMinutesSeconds }}</div>
    </ion-card>
```

in hours-minutes-seconds.ts

```
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

    @Pipe({
      name: 'hoursMinutesSeconds',
    })

    export class HoursMinutesSecondsPipe implements PipeTransform {

      transform(value, args?) {

        let minutes = Math.floor(value / 60);
        let hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
        let seconds = Math.floor(value % 60);

        let timeString = hours + 'hrs ' + minutes + 'mins ' + seconds + 'secs';

        return timeString;

      }
    }
```

Error: 
    Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
        The pipe 'hoursMinutesSeconds' could not be found ("imgs/wp1.png"/>
            Time Smoke Free
            {{ [ERROR ->]seconds | hoursMinutesSeconds }}

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43299610/ionic-3-cant-find-pipe

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you create a `pipe` using this CLI `ionic generate pipe HoursMinutesSeconds` it'll create a shared module called `pipes.module.ts`. So you need to `import` `PipesModule` module inside your page's module file.

Let's think that page is `my-view` then;

*my-view.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyViewPage } from './my-view';
import { PipesModule } from '../../pipes/pipes.module';//<--- here

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyViewPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(BudgetGroupViewPage),
    PipesModule // <--- here
  ],
})
export class MyViewPageModule { }
```